# ¿What does it mean "ARTISAN" in laravel?

Tags: laravel

¿What does it mean "ARTISAN" in laravel, please anyone help me please anyone help me?

Comment: Just search in the web. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/artisan

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not related with any coding issue.

Answer (score 1):

`Artisan` is the command-line interface included with Laravel. It provides a number of helpful commands that can assist you while you build your application.

When you create a new Laravel project, you have a file called `artisan` in the root of your application. You can call this file from the command line with `php artisan` and access a number of convenient command line tools to help you develop your Laravel application.

---

For example, you can create a controller using the following command:

```
php artisan make:controller MyController
```

It's a lot quicker than manually creating a new file, renaming the file "MyController", and copying/pasting the controller class boilerplate.

---

To view a complete list of artisan commands, you can use:

```
php artisan list
```

---

The best place to learn more about artisan is Laravel documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/artisan